# Issue getting a graphic triangle to show on my JPanel east in BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, layout-manager

I've made a GUI using swing with a `BorderLayout` and `GridLayout` in the center. I want to add a triangle I've made in another class to the `JPanel` east in my `BorderLayout` but cant get it to show.

When I set a `bgcolor` for said `JPanel` I got a weird little result, if you like you can have a look at the code: [gistlink](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/326bbfb4faaf1450c3db)

I have a feeling the issue is in the `TriGoButton` constructor but I'm not sure how to test further. I've tried different variations of `paint()` but have never been able to see the green triangle.

---

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel content;
    private JTextField placeTxtField;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestGUI frame = new TestGUI();
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public TestGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setContentPane(content);

                // issue
        JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
        content.add(rightPanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
        rightPanel.add(new TriGoButton());
                // issue?

        JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
        content.add(leftPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel();
        content.add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 3, 0, 20));

        JLabel countyLbl = new JLabel("County");
        centerPanel.add(countyLbl);

        JComboBox countyDropDown = new JComboBox();
        centerPanel.add(countyDropDown);

        JLabel muniLbl = new JLabel("Munipalicity");
        centerPanel.add(muniLbl);

        JComboBox muniDropDown = new JComboBox();
        centerPanel.add(muniDropDown);

        JLabel placeLbl = new JLabel("City or place");
        placeLbl.setToolTipText("search");
        centerPanel.add(placeLbl);

        placeTxtField = new JTextField();
        centerPanel.add(placeTxtField);
        placeTxtField.setColumns(15);
        placeTxtField.setToolTipText("enter w/e");

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        content.add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JButton goBtn = new JButton("Clicky");
        bottomPanel.add(goBtn);
        goBtn.setToolTipText("Please click.");
        goBtn.addActionListener(this);

        JPanel topPanel = new JPanel();
        content.add(topPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JLabel headlineLbl = new JLabel("headline");
        topPanel.add(headlineLbl);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    }

}
```

---

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TriGoButton extends JPanel {

    public TriGoButton() {
        add(new JPanel(), BorderLayout.EAST);
        setBackground(new Color(100,100,250)); //blue //wtf
    }
        public void paint(Graphics g) {  
             super.paint(g);

             int[]x={90,90,300};  

             int[]y={150,0,90};  

             g.setColor(new Color(23,201,10));  //green
             g.fillPolygon(x,y,3);  
        }  

}
```

EDIT: 
////////////

Comment: Please post pertinent code, preferably a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), here with your question, not in a link. Links can go dead, and links may hold large programs, programs too large to ask a volunteer to review. Your compliance with this request will be greatly appreciated and will likely help you in getting better and faster help.

Comment: I would also suggest posing a question to help people answer.

Comment: I've added your code to your question to make it comply with the site's rules.

Comment: You've got a new problem? Shouldn't this be asked in a new question?

Comment: Sure, I just figured they were semi related, my apologies, new here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added your code. I think that your issue is that your TriGoPanel doesn't override getPreferredSize, and so it may be sizing itself quite small. Consider adding to the class something like:

```
   @Override
   public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
      if (isPreferredSizeSet()) {
         return super.getPreferredSize();
      }
      return new Dimension(PREF_W, PREF_H);
   }
```

where you have int constants, PREF_W, PREF_H, for your width and height dimensions.

## __________________________________________________

Edit: and I strongly second everything that MadProgrammer recommended!

Answer (score 3):

1. I don't know why you are adding a `JPanel` to your `TriGoButton` class, but this is going to cause you issues.
2. It's not recommended that you override `paint`, this can cause no end of issues, as the parent container isn't always included in updates when it's children are painted. See [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) and [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details.
3. `BorderLayout` will use the component's `preferredSize` tomake decisions about how it should sized.  Your `TriGoButton` class should override the `getPreferredSize` method and return an appropriate default size..

Comment: 1. Oh yes, removed.
2. am I overriding paint?
3. Thanks!

Comment: @cashmeer: `public void paint(Graphics g) {` -- looks like it to me!